# Store captured image in iOS using swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, ios-camera

i'm working on this assignment where we have to build a custom camera feature and store images into the phone gallery. So i kinda did almost until the camera preview but i'm not sure yet how to capture and store the images using swift 3.

Here's the source code :

```
var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var sessionOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()






override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

    let deviceSession = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera, .builtInDuoCamera,.builtInTelephotoCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .unspecified)

    for device in (deviceSession?.devices)! {

        if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back {

            do {

                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput.init(device: device)

                if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {

                    captureSession.addInput(input)

                    if captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput) {

                        captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)
                        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                        previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = .portrait

                        cameraLayerView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                        cameraLayerView.addSubview(topControllerView)
                        cameraLayerView.addSubview(bottomControllerView)


                        previewLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.cameraLayerView.frame.width / 2, y: self.cameraLayerView.frame.height / 2)
                        previewLayer.bounds = cameraLayerView.frame

                        captureSession.startRunning()

                    }
                }
            } catch let avError {
                print(avError)
            }
        }
    }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated:   false)
}



@IBAction func galleryAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

  // This part shows the thumbnail of a current image been taken
}



@IBAction func captureAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // This is the part i have capture the image

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the picture it's really simple, take a look [here](https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/take-photo-tutorial-ios8-swift).
To present the image picker:

```
func takePhoto(sender: UIButton) {
    imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera

    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Getting the taken/selected image:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
}
```

Now, saving the UIImage to the photo album can be done like explained [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum-how-to-write-to-the-ios-photo-album).
The following call will save the photo to the gallery and call a completion handler:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(yourImage, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
```

The handler is something like:

```
func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        // error
    } else {
        // no error
    }
}
```

Comment: Mostly simplified way thanks will try it out and provide feedback @BogdanFarca

Comment: Apart from using the ImagePicker controller i wish to implement a custom camera is there any resource available you can provide @BogdanFarca

Comment: @SharkesMonken: there is a very good explanation on how to implement a custom camera here : https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Creating-a-Custom-Camera-View

Comment: Thank you for taking time to provide extra details @bogdan

Comment: How can i save image with a name identifier